# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1051fbb50) console prints this: fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift

I am new to swift development and I apologize if this question has already been answered, but I have no Idea why I am getting this error. it will build successfully, but when the buttonTapped gets tapped I get this error and the app crashes.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit

class QuotesViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var quoteLabel: UILabel!


    var quotes : [Quote] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Database.database().reference().child("quotes").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)

            let quote = Quote()
            quote.quote = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["quote"] as! String

            self.quotes.append(quote)
        })

    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        newQuote()
    }


    @IBAction func didTappedLogout(_ sender: Any) {
        // sign user out of firebase
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

        // sign user out of Facebook
        FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(nil)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let SignInViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView")

        self.present(SignInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func newQuote(){  **this is where I get the error**
        let myQuote = quotes[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count) ))]  
        quoteLabel.text =  myQuote.quote
       // print(myQuote.quoteID)

    }
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        newQuote()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the issue was that the signInSegue was out side the credential function like this:**

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    print("Successfully logged in with Facebook...")
    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        print("User logged in...")



    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

it should be like this:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    print("Successfully logged in with Facebook...")
    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        print("User logged in...")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInSegue", sender: nil)


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna guess that your app is crashing because you're trying to access an item in the `quotes` array before Firebase gets the data to put in it. Thus, when you try to get something from it, there's nothing in it, so *every* index (even `0`) is out of bounds. You should check to make sure that there's something in `quotes` first, like this:

```
func newQuote(){
    guard !quotes.isEmpty else{
        // Tell the user there are no quotes yet
        return
    }
    let myQuote = quotes[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count) ))]  
    quoteLabel.text =  myQuote.quote
}
```

Comment: I have added that into the code, which silences the error, but the label is still not being updated with the database query. It was working, before I added the facebool login and logout with the didTappedLogout action.

Comment: i commented out the new quote function and put the code from it directly into the button tapped action. I am now getting an error of index out of range. pointing to the code in the action. Thanks for your help in this, I am a newb to Swift/IOS development.

Comment: on top of all this it works as expected in the simulator, but not on an actual device

Comment: actually I believe that this has to do with the FBSDK listener failing to log in to the database.

Comment: fixed it just now